# xmax in geom_histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have some income data and I am looking to plot a series of histograms by race.

The income for whites has a maximum amount of 615,000, significantly higher than for other races. I want to set an `xmax` at 300,000 in order to help the display but `ggplot` is not responding to my `xmax` command.

```
    ggplot(employeeservices, aes(x=employeeservices$INCWAGE)) 
           + geom_density(xmax=300000) + facet_wrap(~Race2, ncol = 2)
```

Any particular guidance here?

Comment: Questions purely about how to program something belong better on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `xlim` instead of `xmax`.

```
ggplot(employeeservices, aes(x=employeeservices$INCWAGE)) +
  geom_density() + facet_wrap(~Race2, ncol = 2) + xlim(0,300000)
```